# container_of() for pointers

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

I know what `container_of()` does, but I want to obtain a field that is a pointer within some struct like this:

```c
struct A {
    int *ptr;
};

void some_func(int *ptr) {
    struct A *a = container_of(&ptr, struct A, ptr);
}
```

But it seems not working. This is compiled successfully, but looks like it produces wrong pointer:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

struct A {
    int *ptr;
};

void some_func(int *ptr)
{
    struct A *a = container_of(&ptr, struct A, ptr);
    if (a)
      pr_info("%d", *a->ptr);
    else
      pr_info("Ooops");
}

int __init m_init(void)
{
    int ptr = 10;
    struct A a = {.ptr = &ptr};

    some_func(&ptr);

    return 0;
}

void __exit m_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(m_init);
module_exit(m_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

If I do `container_of(ptr, struct A, ptr);` this isn't compiled:

```
error: static assertion failed: "pointer type mismatch in container_of()"
```

I guess this is because `ptr` is a pointer, not a usual `int`, so `__same_type` will return false, so make it a pointer.

can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: `But it seems not working` What do you mean by "not working"? It does not compile? You get an error? What _happens_? Do `container_of(ptr` instead of `container_of(&ptr`

Comment: `container_of` needs the address of a field within a containing object of some type so that it can work out the address of the containing object. In the above code `&ptr` is the address of a function parameter, not the address of a field within a containing object. You would need to define the function as `void some_func(int **ptr) {` `struct A *a = container_of(ptr, struct A, ptr);` `{` and call it with the address of the `ptr` member within some object of type `struct A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work. The reason is that `ptr` in `m_init` is a local variable, so its address `&ptr` is meaningless for reconstruction of an address of the other local variable `a`.

However, you can replace:

```
some_func(&ptr);
```

with

```
some_func(&a.ptr);
```

But will require changing `some_fun` to take a pointer `int*` member of `struct A`. So the argument type must be `int**`.

```
void some_func(int **ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) {
      pr_info("Ooops");
    } else {
      struct A *a = container_of(ptr, struct A, ptr);
      pr_info("%d", *a->ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `&ptr` and `&a.ptr` are the same here, because `struct A a = {.ptr = &ptr}`

Comment: @k1r1t0, the value of `a.ptr` does not matter. Only its address `&a.ptr` is important. The whole trick with `container_of` it to transform a pointer to member to a pointer to the parenting structure.

Comment: @k1r1t0, `&ptr` and `&a.ptr` are **not** the same. Just dump it with `printf`/`pr_info` to see

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got it, my mistake. It's kinda `&a.ptr == &(&ptr)`

Comment: @k1r1t0, very "kinda". The `&ptr` is not an l-value. It does not localize an object (`&ptr = ...` is invalid). So it does not have an address.